# Recorriendo una lista y operando en Python

Tags: python

Estoy encontrando una duda a la hora de recorrer una lista a la vez que opero sobre los datos que recorro. He creado una función que llamaremos *calcula_momento_central* que recibe dos parámetros: *serie* y *grado*. Por defecto, grado=2 y serie es una lista de números que pueden ser int o float.

El momento se calcula como: *momento = ((x1-media)**grado + (x2-media)**grado + ... + (xi-media)**grado) / n* donde media es la media de los valores de la serie y n es el número de valores de la serie.

Mi primera idea fue:

```
def calcula_momento_central(serie,grado=2):
    n = len(serie)
    suma_serie = sum(serie)
    #Para calcular la media y n
    media = suma_serie / n

    momento = sum((serie - media) ** grado)

    return momento/n
```

Esta idea inicial no me funcinó y recibía errores en el cálculo de la media del tipo :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Así que modifiqué varias cosas hasta que me quedó así:

```
def calcula_momento_central(serie,grado=2):
    n = len(serie)
    suma_serie = 0
    for numero in serie:
        suma_serie += sum(numero)

    #Un bucle for para calcular suma_serie y luego calculo la media. Así 
    #dejó de darme errores el cálculo de la media.
    media = suma_serie / len(serie)

    #Al dejar de darme errores el cálculo de la media, me dio errores el 
    #cálculo del momento; así que modifiqué esto también. 
    momento = 0
    for numero in serie:
        momento += sum((serie - media) ** grado)

    return momento/n
```

Sin embargo, no consigo solucionar los errores en el cálculo del momento. La línea "momento += sum((serie - media) ** grado)" me devuelve el siguiente error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error te está diciendo qué ocurre. Estás intentando aplicar el operador `-` (la resta) a dos datos que no se pueden restar, siendo uno una `list` y el otro un `float`.

Efectivamente, eso está ocurriendo en:

```
momento += sum((serie - media) ** grado)
```

Más concretamente, se trata de la operación `serie - media`, pues `serie` es una lista, mientras que `media` es un ´float`.

Tal vez esperabas que python aplicara esa operación *vectorialmente*, es decir, que restara `media` *a cada elemento* de la lista `serie`. No es así como funciona python por defecto, aunque puedes usar la biblioteca `numpy` para tener acceso a este tipo de operaciones vectoriales (luego te cuento cómo).

Sin necesidad de bibliotecas externas, lo que tienes que hacer es iterar dentro de la lista `serie` y realizar tú mismo la operación de restar a cada número su media. En realidad eso habías empezado a hacer en tu segundo código, en el que ya había un bucle `for numero in serie`, pero después en lugar de restar a `numero`, restaste a `serie`. Además aplicabas un `sum()` al resultado, cosa que ya no tiene sentido cuando estás iterando en bucle, pues esa suma es la que vas acumulando en `momento`

Un problema similar tienes al principio, a la hora de calcular la media, pues también iteras en un bucle pero vas llamando a `sum()` sobre cada elemento, lo que tampoco tiene mucho sentido.

La forma correcta sería por tanto:

```
def calcula_momento_central(serie,grado=2):
    n = len(serie)
    suma_serie = 0
    for numero in serie:
        suma_serie += numero

    #Un bucle for para calcular suma_serie y luego calculo la media. Así 
    #dejó de darme errores el cálculo de la media.
    media = suma_serie / n

    #Al dejar de darme errores el cálculo de la media, me dio errores el 
    #cálculo del momento; así que modifiqué esto también. 
    momento = 0
    for numero in serie:
        momento += (numero - media) ** grado

    return momento/n
```

### Usando numpy

Si tienes `numpy` instalado, puedes hacer uso de sus operaciones vectoriales. Un vector `numpy` sí permite una operación como `vector - escalar`, y esa operación se realiza para cada elemento del vector. También tiene muchas funciones típicamente usadas en cálculo matricial y vectorial. Por ejemplo, tiene la posibilidad de calcular la media llamando a una función.

Eso simplificaría tu función:

```
import numpy as np

def calcula_momento_central(serie, grado=2):
    # Convertir la serie en un vector numpy
    serie = np.array(serie)

    media = np.average(serie)
    momento = np.sum((serie - media) ** grado)
    return momento/len(serie)
```